# Settings image on demang for jstree client side (without types plugin)

Tags: javascript, icons, jstree

I want to set the image based on leaf title i.e. if the title of the leaf is `test.html` I want the image url to be set to `img/html.png`.

I want it to be a client-side manipulation only.

My question is if there is an event to hook up to before the data is loaded or modified to the tree so I can modify the image url when the node is loading or being updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out (always shortly after asking here for some reason):

```
$('#file_tree').jstree().bind('model.jstree', function (event, obj) {
    var _tree = return $('#file_tree').jstree(true);

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.nodes.length; i++) {
        var _node = _tree.get_node(id)
        _node.icon = "whatever_icon_path_i_want.png";
    }
});
```